# Those annoying grasshoppers

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics, permutations, restricted-complexity

The problem #6 of IMO 2009 reads:

> Let **a <sub>1</sub>, a <sub>2</sub>, a <sub>3</sub>, ..., a <sub>n</sub>**,  be distinct positive integers and let **T** be a set of n-1positive integers not containing **a <sub>1</sub>+a <sub>2</sub>+a <sub>3</sub>+...+a <sub>n</sub>**,   A grasshopper is to jump along the real axis, starting at the point **0** and making **n** jumps to the right with lengths **a <sub>1</sub>, a <sub>2</sub>, a <sub>3</sub>, ..., a <sub>n</sub>** in some order. Prove that the order can be chosen in such a way that the grasshopper never lands on any point in **T**.

Your task is to replicate it.

---

### Input

Two sets **S, T** positive  integers, with:

1. **S**  having **n** distinct elements
2. **T** having **n-1** elements not containing the sum of the numbers in **S**

### Output

A montonically increasing sequence of positive integers **J = b<sub>1</sub>, b <sub>2</sub>, b <sub>3</sub>, ..., b <sub>n</sub>**,  such that:

1. The numbers **b<sub>1</sub>, b <sub>2</sub>-b <sub>1</sub>, , b <sub>3</sub>-b <sub>2</sub>, ..., b <sub>n</sub>-b <sub>n-1</sub>** are permutation of the elements of **S**
2. **J** and **T** are disjoint

---

1. Your code should use **O(P(t))** search time, where **P(t)** is a polynomial with degree **<4**
2. This is a code golf, so shortest maintaining the rule wins.

Good luck golfing ! Thanks to @MartinEnder for the suggestion !

Comment: I think the complexity bound is intended to be O(t^3) as opposed to o(t^4), but the non-standard way it's worded makes me reluctant to claim certainty. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @PeterTaylor TBH I don't know what O(something) means, but you can see the discussion [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h289051p1562840) (For the original question) to see that you can construct a good sequence within **c*n^2** searches, where **c** is a constant.

Comment: So you should read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or some other resources. Having said that, what you have said means O(t^3), not o(t^4). And (if you didn't know) you can use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to avoid generating unnecessary comments asking for clarification. | What is the parameter `t`?

Comment: I edited what you wrote to the standard way of expressing that. You should check if you agree, and if you did not just mean **O(n^3)**. Right now, algorithms that run in **O(n^3.9)** are also allowed, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @Sanchises, I've rolled back your edit because it required *at least* quartic complexity, which *definitely* isn't what OP wants.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Whoops, yeah, my bad. Do you agree with just "The algorithm must run in **O(n^k)** with **k<4**"? As it stands, it makes zero sense (the OP obviously meant **n** rather than **t**, and **O(P(n))** by definition equals **O(n^k)** with **k** the degree of **P**)

Comment: @Sanchises, your point about n rather than t is well taken, but I still don't know whether OP wants O(n^3) or o(n^4) and it seems that OP doesn't either. Since O(n^2) is apparently possible, O(n^3) should allow at least some room for golfing at the expense of complexity.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fair enough. VTC as unclear until fixed.

Comment: What does `t` means in the formula `O(P(t))`?

Comment: @Sanchises It seems that "The algorithm must run in O(n^k) with k<4" has no difference from "The algorithm must run in O(n^4)". Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @tsh No. An algorithm that runs in O(n⁴) is disqualified, but an algorithm that runs in O(n^3.9) is valid by that rule. But it seems unlikely that a golfing answer would have a time complexity with a non-integer k, so perhaps the OP just meant O(n⁴) (if they don't know the difference between smaller than and strictly smaller than) or O(n^3) (if they are unaware that algorithms may have a complexity with O(n^k) with k a non-integer). Until they come back, we can only guess.